# Ruby on Rails: Delete multiple hash keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I often find myself writing this:

```
params.delete(:controller)  
params.delete(:action)  
params.delete(:other_key)  
redirect_to my_path(params)
```

The trail of deletes doesn't feel right and neither does:

```
[:controller, :action, :other_key].each do |k|
  params.delete(k)
end
```

Is there anything simpler and cleaner?

Comment: When I wrote that the second approach didn't feel right, I meant that given the richness of the Hash API, I suspected that there was some method or idiom already out there for this and a monkey patch wouldn't be necessary.  Maybe not, though.  Many thanks to all who answered!

Comment: Hash#except was exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't remember that it's a Rails core extension so I was puzzled when I couldn't find it in the Hash API.

Comment: Note that strictly the answer is `Hash#except!` but `Hash#except` is the way to go (don't mess with `params`!). As a rule of thumb, don't mess with any object in-place unless absolutely required, the side-effects may be have unexpected results.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

I'm guessing you're unaware of the [Hash#except](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except) method ActiveSupport adds to Hash.

It would allow your code to be simplified to:

```
redirect_to my_path(params.except(:controller, :action, :other_key))
```

Also, you wouldn't have to monkey patch, since the Rails team did it for you!

Comment: Ahhh, I knew I'd seen this before but I couldn't remember where! (Hence my "this doesn't feel right" remark.)  Thanks!

Comment: One of those lesser documented methods. I went looking for something like this while proposing an answer but didn't see it.

Comment: For some reason except didn't work. But `except!` did. Rails 3.0

Comment: Rails 3.2 on ActiveRecord attributes, had to use strings for the keys?  i.e. `User.attributes.except("id", "created_at", "updated_at")` symbols did not work

Comment: Adding to what @house9 mentioned, ActiveRecord `attributes` method returns a `Hash` with keys that are `String`. So then you would have to use string key names in `.except()`. However I get around this using the `Hash.symbolize_keys` a la `@user.attributes.symbolize_keys.except(:password, :notes)` -- using `symbolize_keys` makes it work as one would expect

Answer (score 46):

While using `Hash#except` handles your problem, be aware that it introduces [potential security issues](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#redirection). A good rule of thumb for handling any data from visitors is to use a whitelist approach. In this case, using `Hash#slice` instead.

```
params.slice!(:param_to_keep_1, :param_to_keep_2)
redirect_to my_path(params)
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the security issues surrounding redirection.

Comment: Just a heads up: ActiveSupport, not Ruby itself, provides Hash#slice and #slice! http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Slice.html

Comment: I couldn't get David James's link to work but this one seems to be ok: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice

Comment: undefined method 'slice!' for `{:b=>2, :c=>3}:Hash`

Answer (score 28):

I'd be completely happy with the code you originally posted in your question.

```
[:controller, :action, :other_key].each { |k| params.delete(k) }
```

Comment: without modifying `Hash` this is the best answer :+1:

Comment: I've used this method but replaced params with the name of the hash and then it worked!!  The hash gets mutated.

Answer (score 15):

Another way to phrase dmathieu's answer might be

```
params.delete_if { |k,v| [:controller, :action, :other_key].include? k }
```

Answer (score 7):

Fire up a monkey patch?

```
class Hash
  def delete_keys!(*keys)
    keys.flatten.each do |k|
      delete(k)
    end

    self
  end

  def delete_keys(*keys)
    _dup = dup
    keys.flatten.each do |k|
      _dup.delete(k)
    end

    _dup
  end
end
```

Comment: Monkey patches are a tool of last resort.

Comment: Monkey patches *that replace existing functions* are a tool of last resort.  Monkey patches that add new functions are Ruby 101.

Comment: Should be `delete(k)` instead of `delete(key)`

Comment: For code maintenance the implementation of the non-destructive `delete_keys` should be simply `dup.delete_keys!(*keys)`

Comment: @Phrogz Defining one in terms of the other isn't always a bad idea, but it's just left here unrolled for clarity.

Answer (score 7):

Starting from Ruby 3.0, `Hash#except` is supported directly. This means we would not need activesupport to access `Hash#except`.

From documentation:

Hash#except(*keys) → hash

This method returns a new hash, which includes everything from the original hash except the given keys.

example:

```rb
h = { a: 100, b: 200, c: 300, d: 400 }
h.except(:a, :d) #=> {:b=>200, :c=>300}
```

Reference:

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-except

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you think is wrong with your proposed solution.  I suppose you want a `delete_all` method on Hash or something?  If so, [tadman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560572/ruby-delete-multiple-hash-keys/1560611#1560611) provides the solution.  But frankly, for a one-off, I think your solution is extremely easy to follow.  If you're using this frequently, you might want to wrap it up in a helper method.