# Rails, activerecord, Delete a key value pair from hstore record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hstore

I have hstore in my model like this:

```
store_accessor :properties, :a, :b, :c, :d
```

Let's suppose a record in the database has the hstore column stored like this (note this is not the whole record, just the hstore part shown here):

```
properties: {"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "d"=>"5"}
```

If I want to delete key and value pair "b"=>"2" so that the result is

```
properties: {"a"=>"1", "d"=>"5"}
```

how do I do this in the model code?  I tried this:

```
 update_attribute(:b, nil)
```

But this sets b to nil. I want to delete the key value pair for b not set it to nil.

thanks!

Comment: I think using except method on the 'properties' and then saving the record will help. Try this, but modify according to your needs. -> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227600/how-to-remove-a-key-from-hash-and-get-the-remaining-hash-in-ruby-rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227600/how-to-remove-a-key-from-hash-and-get-the-remaining-hash-in-ruby-rails)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
update_attribute([%(properties = delete("properties",?)), 'b'])
```

OR

```
properties.delete("b")
```

Comment: Please provide more detail in your answer. Explain why this code should help.