# How to collect many attributes from hash in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm wondering if it's possible to collet many attributes from a hash.

Currently using ruby 2.6.3

Something like that

```
hash = { name: "Foo", email: "Bar", useless: nil }
other_hash = hash[:name, :email]
```

The output should be another hash but without the useless key/value

Comment: What's the expected output that would have? An array? or a hash without the useless key-value?

Comment: a hash without the useless key-value. @SebastianPalma

Comment: There is detailed answer for this, with different options to choose from, regarding  how to remove a key from hash and get the remaining hash. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227600/how-to-remove-a-key-from-hash-and-get-the-remaining-hash-in-ruby-rails/39231096#39231096

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Ruby's built in [`Hash#slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-slice):

```
hash = { name: "Foo", email: "Bar", useless: nil }
p hash.slice(:name, :email)
# {:name=>"Foo", :email=>"Bar"}
```

If using Rails you can use [`Hash#except`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except) which receives just the keys you want to omit:

```
p hash.except(:useless)
# {:name=>"Foo", :email=>"Bar"}
```

Answer (score 3):

If useless keys are so for having `nil` values, you can also use [Hash#compact](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-compact):

```
h = { name: "Foo", email: "Bar", useless: nil }
h.compact #=> {:name=>"Foo", :email=>"Bar"}
```