# Meaning for attributes_for in FactoryGirl and Rspec Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, attributes, factory-bot

Looking through a tutorial on controller testing the author gives an example of an rspec test testing a controller action. My question is, why did they use the method `attributes_for` over `build`? There is no clear explanation why `attributes_for` is used besides that it returns a hash of values.

```
it "redirects to the home page upon save" do
  post :create, contact: Factory.attributes_for(:contact)
  response.should redirect_to root_url
end
```

The tutorial link is found here: http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html The example is found at the beginning topic section `Controller testing basics`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`attributes_for` will return a hash, whereas `build` will return a non persisted object.

Given the following factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'John Doe'
  end
end
```

Here is the result of `build`:

```
FactoryGirl.build :user
=> #<User id: nil, name: "John Doe", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

and the result of `attributes_for`

```
FactoryGirl.attributes_for :user
=> {:name=>"John Doe"}
```

I find `attributes_for` very helpful for my functional test, as I can do things like the following to create a user:

```
post :create, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
```

When using `build`, we would have to manually create a hash of attributes from the `user` instance and pass it to the `post` method, such as:

```
u = FactoryGirl.build :user
post :create, user: u.attributes # This is actually different as it includes all the attributes, in that case updated_at & created_at
```

I usually use `build` & `create` when I directly want objects and not an attributes hash

Let me know if you need more details

Comment: Thanks pjam, I understand it now! You are becoming more and more of an rspec mentor for me in overstackflow.

Comment: been looking for this answer all over. One thign though... how would I get around `post :create, user: u.attributes` if some of those attributes aren't accessible in the model?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want, do you mean if some attributes are not in the attr_accessible list ? Then I don't see what the issue is, I might be missing something here

Comment: @AdamWaite check out .except as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560572/ruby-delete-multiple-hash-keys to remove attributes from the hash generated by FactoryGirl.

Comment: I'm getting an error: SyntaxError: unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input
post: :create, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)  ... where after "post:" the console is expecting something else